# Greens identity for laplace operator

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $L(u)= \Delta u$ be the Laplace operator.
I am trying to find the Greens identity for this operator.

To do so I will (try) to use the following Proposition:

Let L be a formal differntial operator and let $L^*$ be its adjoint operator. Then there exists a bilinear function $B: C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)^2 \rightarrow C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)^n$, such that for every domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with a $C^1$ boundary, the Greens identity holds:
$\int_{\Omega}vL(u)-uL^*(v))dx=\int_{\partial \Omega} B(u,v) \nu dF$.

Is far I know that L is self-adjoint.
My Approach was to find some equality such that it does not use the Laplace operator:

I know that one can write, using the dot product:
$\Delta f=\nabla \cdot(\nabla \cdot f)$

With this, I get

$vL(u)-uL^*(v)=v\Delta u - u\Delta v=v\nabla \cdot (\nabla \cdot u) - u\nabla \cdot(\nabla \cdot v)$

I don't really know how to finish this calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the divergence theorem and $\Delta u = \nabla\cdot \nabla u$ to show that for $u,v\in C^2(\bar{\Omega})$ we have the Green's formula
$$
\int_\Omega v\Delta u - u\Delta v = \int_{\Gamma} v \nabla u \cdot \mathbf{\nu} - u\nabla v\cdot \mathbf{\nu} \mathrm{d}\Gamma
$$
with $\Gamma = \partial \Omega$ and $\mathbf{\nu}$ is the outward normal vector to $\Gamma.$